# Using an interface method in java from UML

Tags: java, interface

I know you can't have constrcutors in a java interface. The UML calls for an interface called Circle and has this as what I believe is a method. "+Circle(double x, double y, double r)." In actual code, is this correct?

```
public interface Circle{

     public Circle circle(double x, double y, double r); 


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is valid. What you are seeing is the interface defining a method. The method does not have a body, as you see.

What this means is that any class that implements `Circle` **must** include a `Circle circle(double x, double y, double r)` method with a full implementation.

Basically, the interface guarantees that the `circle()` method will be available in all classes that implement it.